# Qt VS Tools: Error reading VS project settings when trying to create Qt project from template in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt5, qt-vs-addin

I'm trying to create a standard Qt console app in Visual Studio using the Qt templates as provided by the `Qt VS Tools` extension. It initially was working fine, however I got some complier errors, and in trying to fix them I've managed to break the entire process.

Every time I try to create a project from any Qt template, I get the error:

```
QtVSException: Error reading VS project settings
```

Which has the stack trace:

```
Stack Trace:
   at QtVsTools.Core.VersionInformation..ctor(String qtDirIn)
   at QtVsTools.Core.VersionInformation.Get(String qtDir)
   at QtVsTools.Core.QtVersionManager.GetVersionInfo(String name)
   at QtVsTools.Wizards.ProjectWizard.ConfigPage..ctor()
   at QtVsTools.Wizards.ProjectWizard.ConsoleWizard.<get_WizardWindow>b__8_1()
   at QtVsTools.Common.LazyFactory.Get[T](Expression`1 propertyRef, Func`1 initFunc)
   at QtVsTools.Wizards.ProjectWizard.ProjectTemplateWizard.RunStarted(Object 
       automationObject, Dictionary`2 parameterValues, WizardRunKind runKind, Object[] 
       customParams)
```

Above this error is the error:

```
An exception (ArgumentException) occurred.
Message:
   An item with the same key has already been added.
Stack Trace:
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource 
    resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, 
    TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement] 
   (IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 
    elementSelector, 
    IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at QtVsTools.Core.HelperFunctions.SetVcVars(VersionInformation 
    versionInfo, ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at QtVsTools.Core.QMakeImport.QMakeProcess.Run()
```

I'm using Qt version 5.12.12 and Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.8.4, with Qt VS Tools 2022 Version 3.0.2 (but I've also tried version 3.0.1). When linking Qt VS Tools to Qt, I use the `msvc2017_x64` version.

I've freshly reinstalled Visual Studio, Qt, and Qt VS Tools, but I'm still getting the error. I've tried the answers suggested in [Qt VS Tools: error reading VS project settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61942091/qt-vs-tools-error-reading-vs-project-settings) to no avail. Interestingly, when installing Qt VS Tools, it doesn't create the QtMsBuild environment variable, so I've set it myself. I've also set the QTDIR environment variable to my Qt installation directory.

I can successfully create non-Qt projects from templates, so I'm confident it's a Qt issue and not a Visual Studio issue. However, other forums online simply aren't helping.

Below is a screenshot of the Qt version I have linked to Qt VS Tools.

[image]

I had initially created a Qt project that still opens fine, it's just when I try to create a new one. I have no idea what I could have done for it to suddenly stop working, so I'd appreciate any support. Thanks.

Comment: Qt 5.12 is not supported anymore and has not been for a while. I recommend you: 1. Update your Qt VS tools extension to the latest version (3.0.2 as of today) 2. Download the latest version of Qt, 3. Check what your extension lists as its registered **Qt versions** 4. Retry and 5. provide a screenshot of the listed Qt versions if it still fails. Qt 6.X may not be the version you want to use (although you should) but at least, trying with the latest version will help circumscribe the issue.

Comment: @Atmo sorry, I meant to write version 3.0.2, fixed now (although I have also tried version 3.0.1). As for the Qt version, unfortunately I'm stuck using 5.12 for the time being, as my workplace has a very strict software procurement procedure that can be quite lengthy (not ideal, I know). As for your step 5, I can't seem to find anywhere a list of versions the Qt vs Tools supports... you simply provide a path to a Qt installation. I might just be missing something though?

Comment: Tell on my behalf to your IT security guys they deserve being fired: a procurement procedure so strict it results in using unsupported version of a software is in the realm of incompetence (Qt 5.12 stopped being supported in December 2021, i.e. >2 years ago). Anyway Visual studio has a menu called Extensions, in the menubar. Browse into there. Unfortunately, if you can't test with the latest version to narrow things down, I'm afraid I won't be able to help (unless something can be spotted in your screenshot).

Comment: I know, it's very frustrating. It's not even that we're unable to get newer versions, it's that it takes annoyingly long to get them approved and it's not worth the hassle. Anyway, I've posted a screenshot of the Qt version I have linked, I don't think though that it'll give you much info

Comment: I hadn't paid attention but you are using Visual studio 2022 with a version of Qt compiled for Visual studio 2017. Why is that? Can you compile it from source using VS 2022 instead (with `configure` + `nmake`; I cannot remembers the details, I have not compiled Qt from source myself in years)? The only other "strange" thing I see is that you have a repetition in your path: `Qt\Qt5.12.12\5.12.12\ ` ... Finally, it must be noted I do not have a `QTDIR` environment variable on ;my computer, and it works. Unfortunately, this is about the extent of how much I can help you

Comment: It was my understanding that versions of msvc >= 2017 are backwards compatible with previous versions, so using msvc 2022 should work even though it was compiled for visual studio 2017 (I could be wrong though!). I'll try to compile it from source today. As for the repetition, I have no idea if that's an issue... it's just how Qt installed itself

Comment: That is probably true but that was not the point. What I said is that you should narrow down the possible causes for the error as possible, the discrepancy between MSVC 2017 and 2022 is one of them.

Comment: I've since installed VS 2017 and the exact same error appears. I've also updated the question with another error message that I hadn't noticed previously